# How to use VBA Excel Code to display a pop-up message to users that have out of date information

Tags: excel, vba, date, popup

I want to have a pop-up appear when the spreadsheet is opened.

Each tech is required to log their issues in the spreadsheet. When the sheet is opened, I would like it to check for the user's username against the issue list and alert them of any that have exceed their time estimate. If any issue is beyond the estimated time frame, I want the sheet to pop-up a dialog box or windows saying you have Issues A,B,C,, and that those issues need to be closed or extended.

- Col A is issue Number.
- Col B is the date an issue was started.
- Col C is the number of Days expected for issue to be resolved (30, 60, 90, X - using a dropdown menu for these options. X Meaning it is going to be an extended time frame; unknown at entry.)
- Col D is the status either Closed or Open also controlled by dropdown.
- Col E is the closure date which I'm already handling using a VBA code to auto-populate when closed is chosen from dropdown.
- Col F is the name of the tech handling issue.

[SS of Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvbWB.png)

Here is where I am with the code

```
    'DECLARE VARIABLE
        Dim x_matrix As Range
        Dim x_copyrange, sheet_name, issueString, currentTechName As String
        Dim x_step, x_fnl_row As Long
        Dim issIDCol, issStatCol, issTechCol, IssLogDateCol As Variant
        Dim IssExpClosCol As Variant
    'DEFINE VARIABLE
        sheet_name = "Log" 'PUT YOUR SHEET NAME
        issueString = "Alerts have been found to be late, Please extend or Close"
        issIDCol = Columns(1)  'Put Your Report ID Column
        currentTechName = Application.UserName 'returns username currently using sheet
        issTechCol = Columns(6)  'The Tech name column
        issStatCol = Columns(4) ' The Issue Status Column
        IssLogDateCol = Columns(2) 'Column where you are logging the date issue reported
        IssExpClosCol = Columns(3)  '30, 60, 90, X Column
        
        'CREATE MATRIX
            x_fnl_row = Worksheets(sheet_name).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            'Find last row of Log # Col & used to make the loop larger each time an entry is added
            Let x_copyrange = "a" & 1 & ":" & "F" & x_fnl_row
            'sets a1 to bottom of last entry in F as a range
            Set x_matrix = Worksheets(sheet_name).Range(x_copyrange)
            'Sets the parameters for X_Matrix as a range on the worksheet
    
    'LOOP TO
        x_step = Rows(2) 'Skips the header row at the top of sheet so loop will not loop through row 1
        Do While x_step <= x_fnl_row 'Sets the loop to run through the range as long as the final row is farther down then the first row
            'This is your Loop
            'Make your Conditions Here
            'Issue is open and issue date starting is greater than expected closure date.
            'Tech Names Match
            
            
            If x_matrix(x_step, IssExpClosCol) <> "PPSC Closure" Then ' Xmatrix is the whole range (Xstep is the rows of range, tells it what col to search)
                If x_matrix(x_step, issTechCol) = currentTechName And _
                x_matrix(x_step, issStatCol) = "OPEN" And _
                Now() > x_matrix(x_step, IssLogDateCol) + x_matrix(x_step, IssExpClosCol) _
                Then
                    issueString = issueString + x_matrix(x_step, issIDCol) + ", "
                End If
            End If
        x_step = x_step + 1
        Loop
        
        MsgBox (issueString)
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to click [edit] under your question and add all of the information there. If you post additional parts of your question as answers, they will get deleted by the review process because they're not answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted some code below that works based on the how i set up my spreadsheet columns (see attached picture). I think this might be what you are asking for. Take a look see if it will work for you.

```
Sub standard()
    'DECLARE VARIABLE
        Dim x_matrix, y_matrix, z_matrix As Range
        Dim x_copyrange, y_copyrange, z_copyrange, sheet_name, issueString, currentTechName As String
        Dim x_step, y_step, z_step, x_fnl_row, y_fnl_row, z_fnl_row As Integer
        Dim issIDCol, issStatCol, issTechCol, IssLogDateCol, IssExpClosCol As Integer
        
    'DEFINE VARIABLE
        sheet_name = "Log" 'PUT YOUR SHEET NAME
        issueString = "Alerts have been found to be late, Please extend or Close"
        issIDCol = 1 'Put Your Report ID Column
        currentTechName = Application.UserName  'Sound like you need to add your VBA here to know the tech using the sheet
        issTechCol = 6 'The Tech name column
        issStatCol = 4 ' The Issue Status Column
        IssLogDateCol = 2 'Column where you are logging the date issue reported
        IssExpClosCol = 3 '30, 60, 90, X Column
        
        'CREATE MATIX
            x_fnl_row = Worksheets(sheet_name).Cells(Rows.Count, issIDCol).End(xlUp).Row
            Let x_copyrange = "a" & 1 & ":" & "e" & x_fnl_row
            Set x_matrix = Worksheets(sheet_name).Range(x_copyrange)
    
    'LOOP TO
        x_step = 2 'I am guessing you have a Header Row so start at 2
        Do While x_step <= x_fnl_row
            'This is your Loop
            'Make your Conditions Here
            'Issue is open and issue date starting is greater than expected closure date.
            'Tech Names Match
            If x_matrix(x_step, IssExpClosCol) <> "X" Then
                If x_matrix(x_step, issTechCol) = currentTechName And _
                x_matrix(x_step, issStatCol) <> "Closed" And _
                Now() > x_matrix(x_step, IssLogDateCol) + x_matrix(x_step, IssExpClosCol) _
                Then
                    issueString = issueString + x_matrix(x_step, issIDCol) + ", "
                End If
            End If
        x_step = x_step + 1
        Loop
        
        MsgBox (issueString)
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Im getting a Runtime error 13 type mismatch error on running this, Just wondering if its because you put issstatcol and issIDcol as integer instead of string?  i used Application.Username to supply the name of who was using the spreadsheet to cross reference against the tech name as well. I think i understand most of what your doing here took me a bit to muddle through

Comment: IssStatCol and issIDCol are supposed to be integers, they are the column locations, column a=1, b=2....

Comment: Still got me stumped, it pops up the runtime and when i debugged it was getting stuck at IssExpClosCol on the define variable section, i made it into a variant and got it down to x_fnl_row=Worksheets (next line after create matix) and its stuck debugging there.  I was trying to use ("A:A") to define my columns through the define area then went too Columns(1) to see if maybe i was defining them wrong but still notta.  would it matter if my issue numbers are AA-#### (letters and numbers with a dash)

Comment: Share an image of your spreadsheet and code and let’s work with that. It shouldn’t take but a few minutes to trouble shoot.

Comment: tried to share a snip of the code and the debug but evidently some mod blocked it, i can try to post the code not in snip form and see how that goes

Comment: We will need the a screenshot of the spreadsheet. Try to add that to you comment below.

Comment: Wouldnt allow me to add SS to this so i added it as an answer hopefully they allow it this time

Comment: Also i think i understand all of your code now, although i don't understand why you went with x y and z as Dim (just seems like you gave me more Dimensions then i needed?)

Comment: Yeah, it is Just a template that I use. I just didn’t delete everything I did not need. (They were used if I had multiple matrices and nested loops). Glad it worked for you! Cheers!

Comment: still not working BUT i did get it past where it was Debugging at, it was stuck where you declared fnl row but i changed issIDcol out for just 1 (rows.count,1 instead of rows.count,issIDcol) and it debugged past that issue.  Now its stuck on Do While x_step <=X_Fnl_row.  being able to get rid of all those extra Dim's helps clear up some confusion though!

Comment: I see your screenshot. I edited my code in my answer. It should run without a problem without changing anything. Copy and paste and see what you get. Remember you are taking your table and assigning it to the ``` x_matrix``` and then you reference positions in the matrix with your integers like ``` IssLogDateCol ```.Additional comment/Question Does Column B have anything besides dates, Does Column C have anything besides 30,60,90,X?

Comment: Column B has nothing but dates, and Column C is just 30,60,90,X.   And...It finally works, Also just a note, add a space after Close in your issuestring before the "